# Can I travel from the UK to France though my Passport has expired?

Tags: passports, france, ferries, eurostar

My passport has expired and I need to go to France for my best friend's wedding. Is there a way I can get there without needing my passport? I'm a UK resident.

Comment: "UK resident" is not necessarily the same as "UK citizen." What country issued your passport?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112077/can-a-uk-citizen-travel-to-a-country-in-schengen-without-a-passport

Answer (score 2):

No. As a British citizen, you require a passport to travel outside the UK & Ireland. You will not be allowed to board the ferry without a passport, and if you somehow make it to France, you won't be allowed out of the port without a passport.

For example, [here is what Brittany Ferries says](https://www.brittany-ferries.co.uk/information/faqs/travel-information/do-i-need-a-passport-or-a-visa-to-travel-to-france-or-spain):

> You must have a valid and in-date passport or national identity card to travel with us. This applies to daytrips as well as longer stays abroad.

Have you considered using one of the [urgent services](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently) to renew your passport? You can potentially get a new passport within days.

Comment: If you can get to an appointment in Peterborough or one of the other passport offices you can usually get a passport renewed in one day.

Comment: All true, but assumes the OP has an expired UK passport. I don't think that's necessarily true; see my Comment under the question.

Comment: "or national identity card" Wouldn't a driver's license count as a national identity card?

Comment: No, driving licenses are not ID cards. They lack nationality.